# Reverse Graphical network mapping architecture

Tags: networking, architecture

Hi everyone i've got the issue to handle a network that has not documentation whatsoever but is there any tool or procedure in order to create the network architecture model, or i should do it node by node, and graphical modeling with Visio or Dia.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to make the title a bit more relevant to the actual question 'Graphical network mapping', just 'Network mapping' or similar. I'd be interested if you find anything that does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be two types of it, one is very strategic high level architecture which can be made very easily for any executive level reporting purpose and for the technical reference i would suggest you do the node by node and using **visio** can be more efficient and a quality output.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that can do this automatically, but the only one I know of is [OPNET's NetMapper](http://www.opnet.com/solutions/network_performance/netmapper.html). There are probably others, I just don't know what they are.

If you are attempting to map a small network, it is probably easiest to follow the other answer's suggestion and do it manually, node-by-node.